# Gnu Make: rebuild when intermediate files are missing

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using Make to manage data workflows (not building software projects).  I have pattern rules like so:

```
%.B: %.A
    foo $^ > $@

%.C: %.B
    bar $^ > $@

.SECONDARY:
```

Now, if I notice that there was a problem with some of the `.B` files (e.g. a bug in `foo`), I delete the specific `.B` files and do `make` again, but of course the corresponding `.C` files still exist and are newer than their `.A` files, so nothing happens.

Is there a nice way to force `.C` files to be rebuilt when their dependencies are missing?  Essentially I guess I'm looking for a way to promote the `.B` files up to full targets rather than secondary or intermediate.

Answer (score 4):

I never see this problem, even though I do this a lot.
Maybe that's because I never use pattern rules.
Just get a list of targets and use *static* pattern rules.
Maybe something as simple as getting a list of sources using `$(wildcard)`.

```
# List of sources
As := 1.A 2.A 3.A

${As}: ; touch $@

# List of targets
Bs := ${As:.A=.B}
Cs := ${Bs:.B=.C}

# Static pattern rules
${Bs}: %.B: %.A ; touch $@
${Cs}: %.C: %.B ; touch $@

.PHONY: all
all: ${Cs}
```

Leading to

```
$ make all --warn
touch 1.A
touch 1.B
touch 1.C
touch 2.A
touch 2.B
touch 2.C
touch 3.A
touch 3.B
touch 3.C
$ make all --warn
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
$ rm 2.B
$ make all --warn
touch 2.B
touch 2.C
```

Job's a good 'un.

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me -- I did not know about static pattern rules. Digging further, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) says: "Ordinarily, a file cannot be intermediate if it is mentioned in the makefile as a target or prerequisite." Thus, explicitly naming all the files (as in this answer), rather than matching them through patterns, prevents them from being considered intermediate, and thus ignoring them if they are missing. Another benefit is that it obviates the need to use `.SECONDARY`.

Comment: FYI after testing a bit, the rule for creating Bs doesn't have to be a static pattern rule, just the rule for creating Cs.

Comment: @s6mike Just prefer static pattern rules in all cases. They are just more predicatable, and don't hoover up any files you might have lying around your hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to list the actual `.B` files as prerequisites of your `all` target (or some other target, this is built during the run) if you want to be sure they exist after the build is complete.  I'm not sure there's any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you added `.SECONDARY` target to avoid deletion of %.B files and it causes the problem. So you need different workaround instead of `.SECONDARY`.
How about the following:

```
%.B: %.A; cat $^ > $@ && echo B >> $@

%.C: %.B; cat $^ > $@ && echo C >> $@

$(foreach   C,\
            $(sort $(filter %.C,$(MAKECMDGOALS))),\
            $(eval $C: $(patsubst %.C,%.B,$C))\
            $(eval $(patsubst %.C,%.B,$C): $(patsubst %.C,%.A,$C)))
```

Running the above makefile:

```
bash#
$ touch doc.A

bash#
$ make doc.C
cat doc.A > doc.B && echo B >> doc.B
cat doc.B > doc.C && echo C >> doc.C

bash#
$ ls doc.*
doc.A  doc.B  doc.C

bash#
$ rm doc.B

bash#
$ make doc.C
cat doc.A > doc.B && echo B >> doc.B
cat doc.B > doc.C && echo C >> doc.C

bash#
$ ls doc.*
doc.A  doc.B  doc.C

bash#
$ touch doc.A

bash#
$ make doc.C
cat doc.A > doc.B && echo B >> doc.B
cat doc.B > doc.C && echo C >> doc.C

bash#
$ touch doc.B

bash#
$ make doc.C
cat doc.B > doc.C && echo C >> doc.C
```

The workaround generates explicit rule chains for all %.C targets specified on the command line. Unusual workaround for unusual use of GNU Make!

Comment: This usage doesn't seem *that* unusual, I've been doing this with data for years. =)  Thanks for the idea, I'll give it a shot.  It seems like this would get unwieldy really fast though, and it might be easier to write various phony "clean" targets to delete %.C files when they're out out of date and then just "make" again.

Comment: This only works if you run `make foo.C`.  If you run `make all` where the `all` target depends on a bunch of `.C` files, it won't work (`MAKECMDGOALS` will contain just `all`).  You don't show the rest of your makefile or describe your typical usage, so it's not clear if this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved a similar problem like this:

```
# Avoids collisions with filenames
.PHONY: all

# Stops intermediate files being deleted (e.g. content/X.html)
.SECONDARY:

PUBLIC_FROM_ORIGINAL := $(foreach ...)
PUBLIC_FROM_CONTENT := $(foreach ...)
CONTENT_FROM_ORIGINAL := $(foreach ...)
PUBLIC_ALL = $(PUBLIC_FROM_CONTENT) $(PUBLIC_FROM_ORIGINAL)

all: content public

public: $(PUBLIC_ALL)
content: $(CONTENT_FROM_ORIGINAL) $(PUBLIC_FROM_CONTENT)
```

The content files are the intermediate files, but because the content files are rebuilt by make all, they are restored if deleted (regardless of the downstream files) and changes to them get propagated to the public files.

So I think this same approach should work for you, using something like this:

```
%.B: %.A
    foo $^ > $@

%.C: %.B
    bar $^ > $@

make all: %.B %.C

.SECONDARY:
```

I haven't tested this so you might need to use variables in place of the patterns.